# How to extract a set of numbers from variable that returns a string

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm currently trying to parse out a 6-digit verification code that is being sent in an API request's response body along with some text.

For example:

```
GET -> https://api.twilio/com/...
```

The response body returns something like this:

```
 "body": "Your code is 123456."
```

I'm parsing via JSONpath (`$.messages[0].body`) and saving that string ("Your code is {number}") as a variable.

I'm trying to figure out how to then take that saved variable and parse out just the set of numbers from the string.

I've done a lot of stuff, but this is all new to me and I'm learning as I go.

Comment: *I've done a lot of stuff* - add that to the question.

Comment: Your pseudo-JSON is too pseudo- for me.  Can you make it look like syntactically correct JSON so it's less distracting?  Should say: `"body": "Your code is 123456."`

Comment: If the message is always the same and it's always six digits then `"Your code is 123456.".substring(13,19)` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the value '123456' from the given JSON object by using a regular expression like so:

```js
// Assuming you have the JSON object
const data = {
  messages: [
    {
      body: 'Your code is 123456.',
    },
  ],
};

// Access the 'body' property in the JSON object
const messageBody = data.messages[0].body;

// Use a regular expression to extract the number
const code = parseInt(messageBody.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);

console.log(code); // Output: 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract the number: `$.messages[0].body.match(/(\d+)/)[1]`

```js
const response = {
  messages: [
     {
       body: 'Your code is 123456.'
     }
  ]
};

console.log(response.messages[0].body.match(/(\d+)/)[1]);
```

Comment: Yep this is how I ended up solving it after posting the question. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the response will always be consistent, you can use `str.splice()` to get the specific answer and use `Number()` to make it a number data type. So if the response is like what you said and you've saved the answer to a variable called `responseStr`. You can do

```
let code = Number(responseStr.splice(13, 19)) //expect code = 123456
```

Since it is always a 6-digit code, the start index (13) and end index of the code (18) will remain the same. The second parameter should be end index + 1 since the splice is exclusive of the index of the second parameter.

However, if the response may have a different structure but you are sure the code is always a 6-digit verification code, you can use REGEX to find the string and convert it to a number data type. So something like

```
let matchArr = responseStr.match(/[0-9]{6}/g) //expect matchArr = ["123456"]
let code = Number(matchArr[0]) //expect code = 123456
```

where `/[0-9]{6}/g` is the regex for 6-digit number. But you'll need to make sure it is the only number of 6-digit or more in the response or `matchArr` will contain all the combination of substrings that is a 6-digit number or you will need to modify the REGEX to create a more specific match.